# Horizontal UIStackView inside UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard, uistackview

I have a horizontal UIStackView with 3 buttons inside UIScrollView. I'd like the stack to scroll horizontally when the user changes the font size (via Accessibility).

[image: Storyboard]

Right now, when the user increases the font size, one of the buttons gets squashed.

Here are my constraints:

[image: UIStackView constraints]

[image: UIScrollView constraints]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the UIScrollView's content size is set up correctly. Here are some useful parameters.

`scrollVIew.contentInset
 scrollVIew.scrollIndicatorInsets
 scrollView.contentSize`

When the content view is taller than the scroll view, the scroll view enables vertical scrolling. When the content view is wider than the scroll view, the scroll view enables horizontal scrolling. Otherwise, scrolling is disabled by default. You must set your content view size dynamically so when they change the font, the content view gets wider than the scroll view width. You could wrap your stack view in another UIViewController and treat it as a content view.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. When the content view is taller than the scroll view, the scroll view enables vertical scrolling. When the content view is wider than the scroll view, the scroll view enables horizontal scrolling. Otherwise, scrolling is disabled by default. You must set your content view size dynamically so when they change the font, the content view gets wider than the scroll view width. You could wrap your stack view in another UIViewController and treat it as a content view.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Greater Than or Equal constraint between the scroll view and the button on the right was the problem. I changed it to Equal and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this working fine my side and scrolling well.

```
func createHorizontalStackViewWithScroll() {

 self.view.addSubview(stackScrollView)
 stackScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 stackScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: visualEffectViews.topAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.addSubview(stackView)

 stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

 stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
 stackView.spacing = 5
 stackView.axis = .horizontal
 stackView.alignment = .fill


 for i in 0 ..< images.count {
 let photoView = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 85))
 // set button image
 photoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 photoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.height).isActive = true
 photoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.width).isActive = true

 stackView.addArrangedSubview(photoView)
 }
 stackView.setNeedsLayout()

 }
```